# Comparação de dados entre DataGrid e banco de dados

Tags: c#

Olá pessoal estou com um Duvida na minha aplicação, pois nela roda um pocket pc(Coletor) conectado ao mysql  inserindo na tabela produto(IDProduto, cod_barr, Descricao), e do outro lado tem uma aplicação com um datagridview exibindo oq esta sendo inserido na tabela por esse pocket pc, antes de exibir na grid eu  gostaria de verificar se não estou pegando um registro já existente ou trazendo  só os registro que ainda não estão listados na grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você não precisa fazer essa verificação, acredito que seja bem mais simples anular e atualizar o dataSource do seu dataGridView, da seguinte maneira:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.Update();
dataGridView.Refresh();
```

e depois simplesmente preencher novamente o DataSource:

```
List<Produtos> objListProdutos = new List<Produtos>();
dataGridView.DataSource = objListProdutos;
```